# How to convert React class components into functional components and vice versa - IntelliJ

Tags: reactjs, intellij-idea

Sometimes you want to quickly go from a statless component to a stateful component, and I'm thinking if there is some way to make IntelliJ do this for me (without creating a plugin).

For example, going from:

```
const Stateless = ({ propsDestructuring }) => {
  console.log('Some logic');

  return (
    <div>Some JSX</div>
  );
};
```

to:

```
class Stateful extends Component {
  render() {
    const {
      propsDestructuring
    } = this.props;

    console.log('Some logic');

    return (
      <div>Some JSX</div>
    );
  }
}
```

Alternatively going from "Arrow body style" to explicit return would also be useful, e.g. going from

```
const Stateless = ({ propsDestructuring }) => (
  <div>Some JSX</div>
);
```

to:

```
const Stateless = ({ propsDestructuring }) => {
  return (
    <div>Some JSX</div>
  );
};
```

Using live templates would not work in this scenario, as they can't mutate existing code, only insert new. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think this could be something that can be suggested to JetBrains and we can vote for it! https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=66731. Great Idea!!

Comment: This sounds like the kind of thing there may be JSCodeShift codemods for. Here is a codemod to go from classes to stateless components for example: https://github.com/reactjs/react-codemod#pure-component

Comment: You can use Intellij IDEA Javascript code intention "Convert to class" (available from Intellij IDEA 2016.3, I think)

Although there is known issue with it for not generating 100% perfect React code afterwards

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-20913

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IntelliJ 2018.2 now supports this.

> New intention to Convert React class components into functional components.

***Instructions:***

Press on the component definition:

- Mac: <kbd>options</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Windows: <kbd>Alt + Enter</kbd>

It works both ways:

[image: stateless to class component]

[image: class to stateless component]

Referrence: [Development with React](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2018/07/webstorm-2018-2/#development_with_react)

Comment: I have to mention that this command is available only for simple component definitions

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360008429820-Convert-into-functional-component-not-showing-when-i-press-Alt-Enter-on-my-class-component-

Answer (score 2):

You can go from:

```
const Stateless = ({ propsDestructuring }) => (
  <div>Some JSX</div>
);
```

to:

```
const Stateless = ({ propsDestructuring }) => {
  return (
    <div>Some JSX</div>
  );
};
```

By putting your text cursor here:

```
const Stateless = ({ propsDestructuring }) => (
-----------------------------------------^-----
```

And pressing alt-enter to get the following popup:

[image: intellij popup]

Press enter again to select the top result and it'll be converted to an arrow function with braces.

With regards to the function to class conversion, as far as I'm aware there's no way to do that, but you could always try using find and replace to convert:

```
const (.*) = \(.*\) => \{
```

to:

```
class $1 extends React.Component {
```

If you record this to a macro it should speed that operation up a little.